# Click Event of <ion-col> not working in iOS for IONIC 3 Application

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working with **ionic 3** application. My homepage contains a grid of icons and I created a click event for `<ion-col>` that contain icons.

**HTML**

```
<ion-col col-4 text-wrap (click)="changeSubCategory(17)">
    <ion-icon ios="ios-boat" md="md-boat" class="iconstyle primary-font-color"></ion-icon>
    <br>
    <p class="pstyle">Travel</p>
</ion-col>
```

This event works very well on an Android device but somehow it's not working on iOS device. I am also not getting any error in console.

Comment: have you checked this function is calling or not on iOS devices?

Comment: i put an alert in function but that alert also not firing.so i guess function is not calling when i use an iOS device.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the ‘tappable‘ directive to your element.
Like:

```
 <ion-col text-center tappable (click)="presentSortedFoodModal('sugar')">
....
</ion-col>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. My `ion-grid` was inside `ion-list`. i remove `ion-list` and place `ion-gird` outside `<ion-list>` and `click` event start working on the iOS device too.

I am not sure this is correct approach or not but it solved my problem.

better answers still welcome.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did face the same problem, removing ion-list solved the problem for me.